# How to override a block template created using views

Tags: php, templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8

On Drupal 8 I'm trying to override the template of a block created using views. So far I've a file name as *block--views-block--xxx.html.twig* which gives me access to the view fields.

I've to do something like `content.view_build['#rows'].0['#rows']` to get the rows which is pretty awful but I couldn't find any other way. Also I've to set "Show content" on the views settings.

I can not get the pager to work at all. Reading the documentation from Drupal I can not find any clues.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on twig debugger (he's showing, in inspector tools, all templates what used now). 
In inspector tools you see something like this:

```
- html--internalviewpath.html.twig
- html--node--id.html.twig
- html.html.twig
```

Then just create template with this name add you custom architecture. For example: `html--node--id.html.twig`. Check you can hear to, you see this:

```
- html--internalviewpath.html.twig
+ html--node--id.html.twig (now twig use this template)
- html.html.twig
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rather override the view template rather than the view-block template. 
View templates Naming conventions can be found [here](http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates) and the variables you can work with are listed [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21templates%21views-view.html.twig/8.2.x). you can now put the pager, header, rows and other view elements in different sections in template. 

If you need to override the contents of the view rows then you will need to take action according to how you are displaying the content in the view.

If you use a teaser view of content you can override the content teaser template like "node--content_type--teaser.html.twig", or if you use fields in view then you will have to override the fields templates of each field.